# What is a respectful way to refer to a person who has died?

Tags: word-choice

What is a respectful way to refer to a person who has died? Is it OK to call that person "rest in peace"?

> The rest in peace guy was a very generous man.

Comment: In China, we use _Martyr_. Wikipedia even has a particular entry for the usage in China (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyr).

Comment: Dante I don't mean martyr, I mean refering to someone who has died and has been a good person during life.

Comment: @Robusto, I was also wondering how one would go about dying respectfully :)

Comment: This answer may depend on what culture you're in. For example, I've heard that Australian aborigines don't use a person's real name in the period soon after they've died.

Comment: @Dante, *martyr* means something very specific in English, and should not be used to refer to just anyone who recently died.

Comment: @JSBangs I realized that, so I used _in China_ in my comment....

Comment: There's no best most respectful way to talk about people who have died; this can only be answered with opinions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Rest in peace" should always be written as *RIP* (which really is an abbreviation of the Latin). It should not be used as an adjective. Thus, one cannot say

> The **rest-in-peace* guy was a very generous man

except one wants to be extremely informal, but this is certainly not respectful. I propose two options:

1. Use *deceased*:

   > - The *deceased* was a very generous man
2. Punctuate any reference to the dead with *RIP* (written), *may he/she/they rest in peace*, or  *may his/her/their [gentle] soul[s] rest in [perfect] peace*:

   > - The man, *may his gentle soul rest in peace*, was very generous.
   > - He was a very generous man; *may his gentle soul rest in peace*.
   > - Mr. M, *RIP*, was a very generous man.
   > - Mr. M, *may he rest in peace*, was a very generous man.
3. Use *while alive*:

   > - *While alive*, he was a very generous man.
   > - He was a very generous man *while he was alive*.
4. The past tense and tender memories can also suffice, depending on context:

   > - He was a very generous man.

As always, one's tone is most important factor in situations such as this.

Comment: Too many adjectives may signify sarcasm, but again it depends on context and tone. To me, "gentle soul" is a little excessive, and instead I would say, "John, may he rest in peace, was very generous."

Comment: You can also simply say "may he rest in peace" removing the word "soul"

Comment: Just for fun: "Requiescat in Pace" - "he / she / it rests in peace", as opposed the imperative "REST in peace" as we generally think of it in English.

Comment: @Chris It's a subjunctive, so it functions as a third person imperative - "may (s)he rest in peace".

Comment: @JYelton and @Atømix: thanks for the suggestions; wholeheartedly agree.

Answer (score 43):

You can say "late" if you are referring to the deceased's name, or a position from which it is obvious who you mean. This is respectful, formal, and businesslike.

> The late John D. Rockefeller was a very generous man.
>
> My late husband was a very generous man.

But not

> *The late guy was a very generous man.

Comment: AH!!!! I forgot *late*!! +1

Comment: And just to emphasize (because it's apparently not obvious to the OP): *rest in peace* is a set phrase of limited usefulness. It **cannot** be used as an adjective.

Comment: Can this be used in all references to the dead, or only to those that have recently died?

Comment: @Sam - Whats recent?

Comment: @John: Not sure.  The reason I ask is because, for example, "The late Benjamin Franklin" seems incorrect to say.

Comment: @Sam Pearson: Ben Franklin is a well known historical figure. Thus, it would be unnecessary and, perhaps, considered verbose, but not incorrect to precede his name with the adjective *late*.

Comment: I would use "late" only in a context where the person I'm talking to might not know that the person I'm talking about is dead, or might not know that I know. So not at the funeral, for example. The "my late husband" and "my late father" examples fit that perfectly. I wouldn't use it for a famous person who died centuries ago.

Answer (score 8):

I would refer to *the deceased* unless I was aware of a particular sensitivity in the culture or context.

> The deceased was a very generous man.

Some might suggest *the dear departed* but I find this archaic and a little patronising.

Comment: I think it would depend on your personal closeness to the deceased i.e. dear departed suggest being a friend or relative of the departed

Comment: Thankyou Ed that was a good answer, I can't vote, because I'm a beginner. Isn't there a more respectful way that is not parsonizing? For example if the deceased guy is my dad, is it still bad to say dear departed?

Comment: My understanding is that if the deceased is your dad then using almost anything like _dear departed_ would be regarded as too formal and pretentious.

Comment: *Departed* is a euphemism that's quite common in religious contexts, especially protestant groups.  It implies that the deceased is not dead, as in destroyed, but that they have left this world for a better place.

Comment: @oosterwal Indeed, which is why I find it patronising, as would any person not comforted by religious placebos.

Answer (score 4):

He's "Resting".

He's "Definitely Deceased".

He's "Passed On.  Is No more.  Has ceased to be.  Expired and gone to meet his maker.  A stiff!  Bereft of life, rests in peace!  His metabolic processes are now history.  He's off the twig, he's kicked the bucket, he's shuffled off his mortal coil, run down the curtain and joined the Choir Invisible!  This is an EX-PERSON!"

Comment: +1 for Python reference, -1 for the (admittedly unlikely) chance that a non-native speaker picks up one of the phrases.  Net effect: no vote.

Comment: Fair enough, but I felt compelled to post it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to say : " he passed away". Like " he passed away in his sleep" . As far I know.. The term "late" is used in a more formal setting
although " died" is not a disrespectful word.. I think sometimes we tend to conjure a rather violent death

Comment: There are many euphemisms in the English language, designed to soften or blur reality. I think we tend to avoid direct language that evokes emotion, and instead add a barrier of comfort. Occasionally this is needed, but my personal opinion is it is employed too frequently. George Carlin, who died a few years ago, would have no quarrel with my invocation of the most direct term, "died." (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNk_kzQCclo)

Answer (score 1):

Use the person's name, with "late" if you must make it clear they are dead. I think the terms like "the deceased" are too impersonal.

Answer (score 1):

"The departed" is a polite, formal expression that also works, and it's also a popular movie (though I never saw it).

Answer (score 0):

I think the only respectful way to refer to a person who has died is 
when we do not talk about body but we talk about person's ideas, love, theories which has made impact in our lives. Only body dies, not the person's contribution to the world. That is why a "respectful way" is needed as an expression of thanks.

We can say that is person is "no more among us" which conveys the idea that we are referring to the soul which has traveled somewhere else leaving the body behind.