# Which is correct: "has died" or "died"?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, present-perfect, simple-past, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

To me, using *Present Perfect* form means the event can occur again. So, saying

> someone **has** died

may not be grammatically correct.

Also, I noticed (it might be just coincidence):

> passed away

is used more often than

> *has* passed away

Is using *Present Perfect* correct here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is the present perfect tense used instead of the past tense?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/when-is-the-present-perfect-tense-used-instead-of-the-past-tense)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, my question is not about difference between usage of Present Perfect vs. Past. The question is about the particular phrase seen very often (when someone dies)

Comment: *Someone **has died*** (as opposed to *someone died*) when the death is so recent it can be seen as "still ongoing" (or "news").

Comment: Okay, well look at [this previous question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11040/) or [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55146/) for alternatives to **died**.

Comment: You'll usually find *"John has passed away."* as a complete sentence (it's ongoing/news). But *"John passed away last night"* is more reporting a "past" event.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers! See your point. Will wait to see what other people say

Comment: Still cannot justify using "ongoing" in relation to death. Even if it just happened, it [death] cannot be "ongoing". IMO

Comment: You might want to look at [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wife+passed+away%2Cwife+has+passed+away&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), which I think will bear out my point that the more common *passed away* is normally followed by **when**. The less common ***has** passed away* is usually so recent there's no need to specify when.

Comment: It's not the death that is ongoing, it's the "everyone-else-finding-out-about-someone's-death" that is ongoing. I think FumbleFingers' explanations are right on the mark.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The Present Perfect Construction in English has the following uses (cf. McCawley 1971):

- (a) The **Universal** sense of the Perfect, used to indicate that a state of affairs prevailed throughout some interval stretching from the past into the present
  • *I've known Max since 1960.*
- (b) The **Existential** sense of the Perfect, used to indicate the existence of past events,
  • *I have read* Principia Mathematica *five times.*
- (c) The **Stative/Resultative** sense of the Perfect,
  used to indicate that the direct effect of a past event still continues
  • *I can't come to your party tonight - I've caught the flu.*
- (d) The **Hot News** sense of the Perfect, used to report hot news
  • *Malcolm X has just been assassinated.*

This, coupled with the prohibition on the use of Present Perfect with subjects who are dead

- *Madonna has visited Chicago.*
- **Einstein has visited Chicago.*

means that *X has died* is only appropriate in a context in which
the speaker believes that the addressee would not yet know that *X* is dead.

**Executive Summary**: If it's Hot News, use the Present Perfect; but if it's Old News, simple past.

---

> McCawley, James D. 1971. Tense and time reference in English.
> In C. Fillmore and T. Langendoen (eds.), *Studies in Linguistic Semantics*
> New York: Holt, Rinehart and Winston, pp 96-113.

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation. Your answer kind of confirms what other people said in their comments but provides better reasoning

Comment: +1 for a nice summary of Present Perfect usage. After all, who knows how long it will be around, given that 'the term "Future Perfect" has been abandoned since it was discovered not to be' (Douglas Adams)?

Comment: Some people say if you analyse a beautiful piece of nature or art you somehow reduce it, but I'm not one of them. I love seeing the bare bones of something I "know" about language usage (but can't fully articulate) laid bare so clearly. I look forward to closing an endless stream of related future questions in favour of this one!

Comment: It doesn't really matter what comes before the _have_, or what tense it is (Present and Perfect are on offer today). These are the semantic properties of the ***Perfect Construction***, which is one of the parts of the [Verb Phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf). If one learns to look for Constructions instead of spurious "tenses", it's easy enough to see the bones and sinews.

Comment: @JohnLawler, How about "All the great thinkers of our time, including Einstein, have visited Princeton"? The example is from Declerck, Reed, and Cappelle 2006.

Comment: First approximations only in answers to questions like this. Sentences like those are the kind that keep syntacticians awake.