# Meaning of "She hasn't won an a tennis championship for two years."

Tags: meaning, negation, present-tense, perfect-aspect

> she hasn't won an a tennis championship for two years.

Does this sentence mean she won a championship two years ago or she didn't  win a championship two years ago?

Comment: Hello, welcome to English Language and Usage SE! I advise taking the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a feel for how the site works. Questions are expected to show some research so that answers can focus on explaining things that aren't already explained elsewhere. In this case, research would just consist of explaining what you already know about the use of the present perfect, and why you are unsure of the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: The answers to this question might be helpful to you: [Present perfect used in the negative](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70302)

Comment: "For two years" should be read to mean "for a duration of two years".

Answer (score 1):

Correcting your sentence:

> She hasn't won a tennis championship for two years.

Alternately:

> She hasn't won a tennis championship in two years.

Those mean that either:

- Two years have passed since she last won a tennis championship.
- She hasn't won a tennis championship since she began trying to do so two years ago.