# Present perfect or simple past

Tags: present-tense, present-perfect-vs-simple-past, perfect-aspect

Why is it better to use simple past than present perfect in the first six  sentences?

1.Did you win the game of chess? 
2.Did you see Ann?
3.Did you call Jane?
4.When did you join the company?
5.Did you watch her new movie?
6.Did  you watch the new movie?

You haven't listened to a word, I have said. (Is correct according to the test, but is simple past also possible?)

Where is my bike? It_*was****_*** outside the house, but it’s not there now. (be)

was(My choice)
has been

It_**_*stopped*__*_*__** raining for a while, but now it’s raining again. (stop)

has stopped
stopped

The police_**arrested_*_*__**_three people, but later they let them go. (arrest)

arrested my choice
have arrested

The town is very different now. It_*has changed****_*__*_*_**_a lot. (change)

changed
has changed my choice

Comment: (4,5,6) is the only one where it is clearly better. For the others, the choice of simple past/present perfect depend on the circumstances. And for (5,6), I think that's because you're using the verb *watch* rather than *see,* which is a subtlety that you shouldn't be worrying about in ESL classes.

Comment: I just remebred that is is always better to use simple past after 'when'.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299

Comment: Check out the duplicate, and also the other that is linked in the comments there. If you are still confused, you can edit this question, pick one or two examples (instead of ten) and clarify why exactly is confusing you. Then we might reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For items 2 and 3, it is *not* true that the simple past is preferable. Without any contextual signs that the "see" and "call" actions happened in the past, the present perfect would be "better."