# Quirks and limitations of Past Perfect

Tags: tenses, writing, past-perfect

I know that English has *two* past tenses, when the second past (*Pluperfect*) is farther back in time then the other (*Simple Past*). Reading stories in English, I've discovered that many stories are narrated by the author in past, with present tenses used only in quotes to convey what a character utters. And if the author wants to narrate what happened before the normal point of reference, he uses *Pluperfect*. The author adds **had** before *every* verb (***had*** given). After a series of such verbs, when I start to see normal verbs in the *Past Simple* (*gave*), I understand that the author has ended the digression in the *double past* and come back to his or her normal point in time.

The following is an example from *The Giver* (Lois Lowry). I have marked with *[start]* and *[end]* the passage when the author digresses in the *double past*.

> It was almost December, and Jonas *was beginning* to be frightened. No. Wrong word, Jonas *thought*. Frightened meant that deep, sickening feeling of something terrible about to happen. Frightened was the way **[start]** he **had felt** a year ago when an unidentified aircraft **had overflown** the community twice.
>
> Instantly, obediently, Jonas **had dropped** his bike on its side on the path behind his family’s dwelling. He **had run** indoors and stayed there, alone. **[end]**
>
> *Now*, thinking about the feeling of fear as he *pedalled* home along the river path, he *remembered* that moment of palpable, stomach-sinking terror when the aircraft *had streaked* above.

(The last verb *had streaked* is not the "double past", it tells us what *has just happened* and has its *consequences* in the point of reference.)

---

I have two general questions and one optional (*):

1) When an author digresses in the "double past", does he or she lose the possibility to distinguish which event happened before another? I mean, when you narrate in the present tense, you have three points in time (I don't include the future), when you narrate in past, you have 2 points in time. But in the double past, there is *only one* that you are in. In this case does the author have to rely only on the context and time expressions such as *before* and *after*?

2) When you change narration from the present to the past tense, *Present Perfect* and *Past Simple* assume the same form (as the last verb in the quoted passage). For example if in the present I say: "He **has seen** the plane and now *is* running away. The same plane **attacked** their village a year ago." When I put it in the past it becomes: "He **had seen** the plane and now *was* running away. The same plane **had attacked** their village a year ago." As you see, different tenses have assumed the same form. My question: Do I always have to rely on context to distinguish when an event has its consequences in the point of reference, and when it doesn't?

3*) Can you point out some ideas that can enhance my comprehension of the *Past Perfect Tense*?

Comment: It's technically not a "tense", but it certainly is a construction, a Perfect construction (_have_ + `Past Participle`) with a Past tense form of the auxiliary _have_, instead of a Present tense form (_has, have_), an Infinitive form (_have_), or a Present Participle form (_having_). The [Perfect construction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299) has four principal senses, which are shifted back with the frame of reference, as you point out, by the Past tense marker.

Comment: As for the narration questions, consult your favorite English authors. If you like it, it must work, right? Steal every writing technique you can from the folks who do it right; that's what they're out there for.

Comment: You can always use adjectives or adverbs to distinguish times (e. g. *earlier*). You haven't lost the ability to distinguish times; you've lost the ability to use verb tenses to distinguish times.

Comment: And when you put *ago* into the past, it becomes *before* (or a similar adverb). So the correct way to put it into the past is: *The same plane had attacked their village a year before.* And here *before* tells you the event happened previously.

Answer (score 3):

Linguists call the perfect forms "aspect" not tenses, but that's probably not terribly important here.

1) Yes, the sequence of past/present-perfect forms doesn't imply sequence. If the author needs to specify sequence, he/she needs to change the time.

2) In the quoted passage, the last verb IS past-perfect. What makes you think otherwise? He is remembering the aircraft from earlier. Without "had," it would say that *another* aircraft flew overhead and triggered his memory.

3) I think you have a very good understanding of the English past/present-perfect. I just think someone confused you with bad information on this one sentence.

Comment: Another way to check that the last verb is past perfect is to shift it forward. You get *"he remembers that moment of palpable, stomach-sinking terror when the aircraft streaked above."* Using *"has streaked"* isn't possible in that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Perfects are used to imply that an event is related to other events before / during / after. The tenses look similar but they all convey different meaning about the context of an action / event and usually imply relation to other events.

> The participle is the 'action' verb: runs, attacks.
>
> The verb is modified (had, was, has, is, will be, etc.) - with when,
>
> Additional information:

```
 is it still happening? (progressives - participle has -ing usually) 
 will it happen again?  how long did it last? was it a big deal? how big? has it happened before? is that time still happening? etc.
```

Perfect tense:

- simple present perfect:

  - 'He ***has** seen* the plane || **has** + verb,
- present progressive:

  - and ***is** running* away.  || then something else happened.
- past perfect:

  - The same plane ***had** attacked* their village a year ago.
- past perfect progressive:

  - He ***had been** running* for hours.
  - He ***has been** running* for hours.
- Right now, we infer past events:

  - He ***will have been** running* for hours.
- those events that happened, became these events that are happening:

  - At this rate, he ***will be running*** all the way home!
- and we predict what will happen at the end of these ongoing events:

  - At this rate, he ***will have run*** all the way home!
- and we expect those events to happen and altogether, the events will mean:

  - At this rate, he ***will have had been running*** all day.

[Here's a chart.](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/english_tenses.htm)

Comment: *"He will have had been running all day"* is not English.

Comment: Yes, it is, although it mixes up _future perfect continuous_ and _past perfect continuous_.  It should be, _He will have been running all day._