# Present Perfect or Past Simple to express duration in the past?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, perfect-aspect, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

> *Have you ever danced?*

This is kind of a usual question. What if I want to ask someone about his experience and find out how long it lasted. Can I say

> ***Have*** **you** ever ***danced*** **for** 5 hours?

(and we're just sitting in a cafe and talking about it) Or do I have to put it like this

> ***Did*** **you** ever ***dance*** **for** 5 hours?

Comment: Some people say Brits prefer "Have you ever..." while American usage tends to be "Did you ever..." (but that's not universal). [Here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1762193)'s some discussion.

Comment: There's no difference; either can be used. Depends more on how many syllables you want than anything else. This use of the Perfect, by the way, is the Existential sense, one of the [four senses of the Perfect Construction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299).

Comment: @n.m. I really don't think that's true.

Comment: Obligatory Mitch Hedberg: I haven't slept for ten days, because that would be too long.

Answer (score 2):

**Have you ever** is usually used to reference an indefinite time in the past. **Did you ever** implies a more specific time. For example:

> Have you ever played chess?
>
> Did you ever finish playing that game of chess?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a belief that the simple past/present perfect ("have you ever"/"did you ever") distinction is a Brit/American thing, but I disagree. I would say that in standard American usage, using the simple past to talk about things that happened or may have happened over an indeterminate period of time is incorrect.

To my ear, constructions like "Did you ever try Hawaiian pizza?" or "I never danced for 5 hours" sound East Coast and a bit "street" to my ears. It could be the case that for certain regional dialects, this is perfectly acceptable, but if such a thing as standard American can be said to exist, it is wrong.