# Grammar Question: "have never read"

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

> I am afraid I ***have never*** read Life of Pi, the novel by Yann Martel.

Is this sentence wrong? If not wrong, is it sloppy? To me it seems more appropriate to say:

> I am afraid I ***never*** read Life of Pi, the novel by Yann Martel.

If neither is wrong, which is the better way of writing?

If possible, could you also contrast the inclusion/exclusion of "have" in the "have never" in the sentences below?

> 1. I ***have never*** read anything so stupid in my entire life.
> 2. I ***have never*** been to the USA.
> 3. I ***have never*** eaten at that restaurant.
> 4. I ***never*** read the books; I only attended the lectures.
> 5. I ***never*** lied.
> 6. I ***have never*** lied. [sentence seems wrong]

On a side note, would the sentence be improved if it is made less wordy?

> I never read Yann Martel's Life of Pi.

Comment: "I have never lied" is not wrong grammatically, it's just not something any human being can say truthfully. ("I never lied" implies a previously-defined timeframe or situation to which it applies, whereas "I have never lied" applies to your entire life.)

Comment: I believe that "have never" applies to time only up till now.  (The difference between "never lied" and :have never lied" seems to be one of emphasis.)  In order to apply to an entire life, I think "I will have never lied" would be better.  One could say, "I have never gone skiing" - quite truthfully - and then, next season, learn how to ski.

Comment: related and the accepted answer is very thorough http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63256/which-is-correct-has-died-or-died

Answer (score 3):

The sentence isn't wrong and it's not sloppy.
When using *have never read* or *haven't read* you are describing your current state using Present Perfect (Existential) tense. You are allowing that that might change in the future.

When using *never read* one is typically speaking of a bounded time frame in the past (like while at school) and that state is now unchangeable.

So you might use the first sentence if you and a friend are talking and they make a reference to the book and you admit that *you've never* read it (but it's on my list of books I want to read). I should note here, that you can still use PP even if you don't plan on ever reading:  *I've never read it, and I don't ever plan to because I don't like tigers.*

You might use the second sentence if you and a friend are talking and they make a reference to having read it for English class in 9th grade and you then admit that *you never read* it (while in high school).

As far as shortening it, it all depends on what your point is.  You've changed it to a statement of fact but lost the apology.  If the apology was the your main reason for making the statement, cutting that out wouldn't be very helpful.

Comment: It's not present perfect continuous. That would be _I have never been reading_, which is not really correct here. The use of the perfect construction here is the [Existential Sense](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299), "used to indicate the existence of past events, e.g, *I have read* Principia Mathematica *five times.*" In this case, because _never_ is negative, it would be the **nonexistence** of past events that's indicated.

Comment: @JohnLawler- Thanks.  Of course you are right.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can say this and it sounds best to my ear:

   I am afraid I have never read (pronounced red) Life of Pi, the novel by Yann Martel.
2. You can say this, and it sounds okay but not as right as #1:

   I am afraid I never read (pronounced reed) Life of Pi, the novel by Yann Martel.
3. It does sound odd to say this, and this may be what prompted your question:

   I am afraid I have never read (pronounced reed) Life of Pi, the novel by Yann Martel.
4. It does sound somewhat odd to say:

   I am afraid I never read (pronounced red) Life of Pi, the novel by Yann Martel.