# Present perfect and its interpretation

Tags: grammar

I have a question.

Does this mean the consequence or the continuous state?

> A half century past the beginning of the movement, it's been invested with an aura of mystique.

I think it can be both...
What is your take?

Thank you.

Comment: I would say it means that a continuous state _is_ the consequence of the action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my eye this is a resultative present perfect; but it is very easy to see why you might think it is a continuative present perfect:

- The verb here is ambiguous. *Has been invested* may be parsed as either the present perfect passive of the eventive verb *INVEST* or as the present perfect of the stative verb *BE* + the present participle of *INVEST* employed as an adjective.
- At first glance, the temporal expression which introduces the sentence looks like it's defining just such a duration as a continuative perfect requires:

  > A half century past the beginning of the movement

  But in fact what this defines is not a duration but a location, a single point: now.

  > The movement has now been invested with an aura of mystique.

The inferences you may draw are that:

> The movement, at its beginning, did not have an aura of mystique.
>   At some later point it was invested with an aura of mystique.
>   As a result it now possesses an aura of mystique.

That's a classic resultative perfect:

> (2)a. Resultative: There is one event of the type denoted by the base sentence
>   in the interval terminating at the evaluation point, and its direct result
>   holds at this point.
>     b. Policeman (on road): Can I see your license please. Driver: I’ve left it at
>   home.
>     Anita Mittwoch, "The English Resultative perfect and its relationship
>   to the Experiential perfect and the simple past tense", *Linguistics & Philosophy (2008) 31:324
>   .

Comment: The dialogue in the last quote feels like UK usage; I'd use the simple past there if I were the driver. And "continuative" is a little too much like "continuous" to be a helpful term for the perfect. I prefer [McCawley's terms for the four senses of the perfect construction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299): _Universal, Existential, Stative/Resultative,_ and _Hot News!_

Comment: @JohnLawler I've seen a variety of terms for *Universal*, *Existential* and *Stative*, none of which are entirely satisfactory. As for *Hot News!*, a couple of my sources state that McCawley withdrew it in 1981 (on the grounds that it's a subset of the Existential) in an article to which I don't have access: 'Notes in the English present perfect', *Australian Journal of Linguistics* 1.81-90. A pity, since that's the only one of McCawley's terms I thought entirely apt.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'd probably use the present perfect here, but I was raised by English teachers.