# Can we put the adverb of time on the present perfect tense?

Tags: grammar

Can we put the adverb of time on the present perfect tense?
*i have just moved here last month.*

Comment: Yes, just as long as it's viewed (by the speaker and/or the listener) as [Hot News](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299).

Comment: @JohnLawler's comment notwithstanding,  That just doesn't sound right to me. I might say, "I have recently moved here." or "I have just recently moved here." But adding a specific time just hurts my ears.   For me the specific time needs a change to simple past:  *I just moved here last month*"

Comment: @Jim, the 'specific time' by itself at times serves to define the 'hotness', without that it might not have the force of immediacy in a certain context. "What! Relo again? I've just moved here last month!"

Comment: @Kris- If you say so.  You'd never catch me saying that.  It'd be "I just moved here last month." and to me the *just* brings the sense of immediacy.

Comment: May as well mark this as a potential duplicate of [Which is correct: "has died" or "died"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63256/which-is-correct-has-died-or-died)

Answer (score 1):

As John Lawler suggests in his comment, the use of the past perfect may not be the best choice of tense in this type of sentence for the reasons listed in the [linked question and answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63256/which-is-correct-has-died-or-died/63263#63263).

More common constructions to convey the sense of your sentence would be

> *I just moved here last month*.
>
> or
>
> *I moved here just last month.*