# has just had or just had a baby

Tags: grammaticality, adverb-position, focusing-adverbs

My question is not whether the correct grammar is either "She has just had a baby" or "She just had a baby".
I am aware that the official grammar is "She has just had a baby".
But in a way that sentence sounds wrong.
It is correct in the meaning that it follows the grammar rules and guidelines.
However, when you "have just had a baby", somewhere in my mind it is as if that person is still having that baby. As in, the birth is still going on.
But when you say "She just had a baby", the birth is done. It's finished.
Which is (hopefully) the case.

So my question is actually more of a wiki-question expecting opinions on the implementation rather than a question expecting a valid and factual answer.

Comment: The sense of _have_ in the idiom _have a baby_ is different from its normal sense of possession, in that _possession_ is durative and does not "take place" as an event at a single time (though _acquisition_ can). In other words, _have_ here refers to a Change of State, rather than a State. That's the reason if feels strange to use the [Hot News sense of the Perfect Construction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299) with _have a baby_, because normally a durative predicate in the perfect continues in the present. But _having a baby_ is an event; it only begins the duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*She has just had a baby* is absolutely idiomatic in British English.

I observe that *She just had a baby* seems to be idiomatic in American English (and has been creeping into British use over the last few decades); I think *she has just* is also idiomatic in American usage, but I'm not so sure of that.

Your understanding of the perfect is not quite right (unsurprising, as it's very subtle). You're right that it means the speaker is thinking of the action as having present relevance; but it does not imply that she is still having it.
It's more that the *just* brings the event so close to the present. I would hardly ever use the simple past with *just* - in my idiolect they are inconsistent.

[Of course there is a different meaning of *just* which I do use with the simple past, *just* meaning something like *only*, as in *I just touched it and it fell!*.]

And by the way, there is no such thing as "the official grammar".

Comment: Makes more sense now. So basically it would be more correct to say: "She (timeframe1) had a baby (timeframe2'"? Timeframe1: e.g.: recently. Timeframe2: e.g.: a few minutes ago. Also, if you use "just" as time indication in "I just touched it and it fell", it sounds so stupid that it makes me laugh :) so I'd never use it that way either.

Comment: @MilanXsD: sorry, I don't understand what you are asking in that comment. And the _just_ in _I just touched it and it fell_ is **not** a time indication: that was my point.

Comment: I know what your point was don't worry :) what I meant to say is: Instead of using "just", would it be better to use time indications such as "a few minutes ago" or "recently"?

Comment: Sorry I was unable to pick your answer as solution becuase of the terribly slow internet connection at work.

Comment: I have returned from my epic quest for reputation to give you an upvote :)

Comment: @MilanSxD: _She just had a baby_ in the non-temporal sense is unlikely, so in most contexts the temporal sense is unambiguous. As I say, in my idiolect I wouldn't say it, but for those who would, it is fine.

Answer (score -1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> The sense of *have* in the idiom *have a baby* is different from its normal sense of possession, in that *possession* is durative and does not "take place" as an event at a single time (though *acquisition* can). In other words, *have* here refers to a Change of State, rather than a State. That's the reason if feels strange to use the [Hot News sense of the Perfect Construction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299) with *have a baby*, because normally a durative predicate in the perfect continues in the present. But *having a baby* is an event; it only begins the duration.