# Can we say: "The summer has been over" for a recently finished event?

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect

I am studying Present Perfect now and I am wondering if it is correct to say, for example:

> The summer has been over

Comment: No. Not with _be over_. _The summer has been pleasant/rainy/slipping away from us,_ but in the present tense _over_ must refer to a past punctual event, not a duration, which is what the present perfect would require. See [here for more](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299).

Comment: But it would be found in a sentence that continued as _The summer has been over for several weeks now._

Comment: I would suggest: "*Summer has ended*" with its simple past equivalent "*Summer ended*" being the most common way to express the conclusion of a season. The verb *end* is easier and sounds more natural in the present perfect. Saying: *Summer has been over* sounds incomplete and is open to misinterpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the correct answers in comments:

*Summer has been over* - This sounds rather incomplete although grammatical.  Most native speakers would reserve this structure for use with a time frame.  For example, *Summer has been over for two weeks.*

If you wish signal the end of summer, you have a few choices:

> **Present tense:**  *Summer is over.*

This gives a sense that summer has ended within recent memory.  But, you can correctly say this in Winter, it is still a fact that Summer is over during the Winter.

> **Past tense:**  *Summer was over* or *Summer ended.*

This is perfectly acceptable as a stand alone.  But, unless it is a bit of exposition setting the scene of a book, most would attach a time frame to this.  *Summer ended 4 weeks ago.*

> **Present Perfect:** *Summer has ended.*

This gives a sense that summer has just concluded recently.  Compare this to the example you provided of *Summer has been over* which implies that it ended at some point in the past.

> **Past Perfect:** *Summer had been over.*

Again, using the verb be here makes a native speaker listen for the completion of the sentence (usually with a time frame).

> **Continuous Present:** *Summer is ending*

It's happening as we speak.

> **Continuous Past** / **Past Perfect Continuous:** *Summer was ending.*  *Summer had been ending.*

Summer was ending while something else was going on.  Again, like the past tense, most uses for this would be in introducing exposition.  (The PPCont sounds awkward.)

> **Perfect Present Continuous:** *Summer has been ending.*

This is another that leaves a native speaker listening for the ending of the sentence.  This has the limited use of a sentence like:  *Summer has been ending with higher temperatures every year.*

The **tl;dr** version:  Using the verb *to end* will be easier in most cases than *to be + over*.