# 'Belong to' or 'have belonged to' - simple present or present perfect?

Tags: verbs, word-usage, present-perfect, present-tense, simple-past

Which sentence is correct?

> I have belonged to the tennis club for three years.

OR

> I belong to the tennis club for three years.

I would appreciate it if someone would kindly answer my question.

Comment: Hi akiko. Your question will fit better on the [English Language Learner's Stack Exchange](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You may also wish to look at these questions and answers: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63256/which-is-correct-has-died-or-died

Answer (score 3):

> I have belonged to the tennis club for three years.

This is correct. You could also say:

> I belong to the tennis club *and have done so* for three years.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer:

> *I **have belonged** to the tennis club for three years.*

or:

> *I **am** a member of the tennis club.*
>
> *I **belong** to the tennis club.*