# When we express the nearest past, can we use 'present perfect'?

Tags: present-perfect

In the various usage of present perfect, I heard that there is a usage of expressing the nearest past like 'I've kicked the dog.'
What percentage we used 'present perfect' to express 'the nearest past' in all usage of present perfect?

Comment: I suggest you find another example. *HAVE got* is not a perfect in AmE, and is only sometimes a perfect in BrE. Usually it's an idiom equivalent to *HAVE*, employed only in the present tense.

Comment: You don't get percentages unless you count them yourself. Sorry. As for [the uses of the perfect,](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299) there are four, and one of them -- the Hot News! sense -- is used for the most recent past: _Botswana has invaded Switzerland!_ One test for this is the use of the adverb _just_;  _Botswana has just invaded Switzerland!_ as well as _I've just kicked the dog._