# Is "it's suddenly come back to me" correct in tense?

Tags: phrases, idioms, tenses

I searched the phrase *it's suddenly come back to me* in [Google books](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&q=%22it%27s%20suddenly%20come%20back%22&oq=%22it%27s%20suddenly%20come%20back%22&gs_l=serp.3...2388093.2396047.0.2396226.24.16.0.0.0.0.419.2311.2-2j4j1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..17.2.608...0.043DV78rk8I) and found that it's been used many times in a lot of books. However, to me this phrase just seems weird. IMO it should be rewritten as *it suddenly comes back to me* which is more natural. I'm not a English grammar guru and not sure which is correct. Hope someone can help me to clarify. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You understand that "It's suddenly come back" means "It _has_ suddenly come back," the recent past.

Comment: D'oh, so the *come* in *it's suddenly come back* is the past participle form right?

Comment: Yes. I just remembered. This memory just now arrived (has just arrived, has returned, **has come**) back to my mind.

Comment: This is the ["Hot News!" sense](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299) of the present perfect construction.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It doesn't mean - It is suddenly come back to me
It means - It has suddenly come back to me