# usage of present perfect and past tense when it comes to people who passed away

Tags: grammar, expressions, present-tense

If the persons I am referring to are no more, in that case which of these is right?

a) He has met them (they are no more) many times, or

b) He met them many times.

( Here I get confused whether the subject himself is no more or the people he met are no more).

Comment: Here is another example I can provide regarding my doubt.. a) Peter has met Steve( Steve is no more) many times, or b) Peter met Steve many times.( Here I get confused whether Peter is dead or Steve is dead.

Comment: [You can't use the present perfect construction with a dead person as subject](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299). So  *_President Kennedy has never slept here_ is ungrammatical. *_I have never met President Kennedy_ is also out, but only because the meeting is impossible in the present. That would also apply to your example.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.John Lawler. So, the right one would be " I never met president Kennedy" ?, as Mr. Kennedy is no more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is correct: "has died" or "died"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63256/which-is-correct-has-died-or-died)