# Present perfect with the adverb yesterday

Tags: grammar, tenses

I have a question about using the adverb *yesterday* with the present perfect.

While reading this book - "Grammar for English Language Teachers" (Martin Parrot), I came across this passage -"We occasionally choose to use the present perfect simple with expressions of finished time (I have seen him yesterday) because, despite the adverb yesterday, we feel that the event is within a present time period. However, it would be confusing to draw learners` attention to examples like this. Page – 248.

The same kind of interpretation is given in the **Cambridge Grammar of the English Language** by Geoffrey. K. Pullum and Rodney Huddleston.Page -144/145.

**Past time adjuncts in experiential perfects** - This use of the present perfect allows for the inclusion, under restrictive conditions, of a past time adjunct:

i.a. He has got up at five o`clock.

iia. We`ve already discussed it yesterday.

i.b. He got up at five o`clock.

iib. We discussed it yesterday.

In [ia] *at five o'clock* is a crucial part of the potentially recurrent situation: the issue is that of this getting up at this early hour; there is no reference to any specific occasion, as there is in the simple preterite [ib]. In [iia] the ‘already’ indicates that I`m concerned with the occurrence of the situation of our discussing it within a time-span up to now and cancels the normally excluding effect of ‘yesterday’ evident in [iib].
The implicature may be weaker: that the same kind of situation is still possible. Nixon has been impeached, for example, can still be acceptable even though Nixon has since died, given a context where the issue if the occurrence within the time-span of situations of the kind ‘impeachment of a president’.

Is this usage of the present perfect grammatical? How often is it used and in what context? What other time adverbs can be used with this usage?

Here is another example of this usage:

[image]

Comment: Your first two questions seem to have been answered by your research. Are you doubting the judgement of the authors? As to the third, an exhaustive list of adjuncts denoting temporal location that may be used in clauses like this seems a tall order.

Comment: Presumably chyrons in rolling news fit the criterion where you "feel that the event is within a present time period".

Comment: *What other time adverbs can be used with this usage?* Any denoting a recent event in time, based on the sources you cite: you can come up with an approximate list but whether "at 5 am" belongs on it will be situationally-dependent. As an aside, questions asking "List every case where this happens" tend not to be successful, it's better to ask about a specific situation, providing as much information as possible on the context.

Comment: @DW256 Both of them are renowned linguists and their explanations seem quite understandable but since this is the first time I have come across this usage, I don`t know precisely in what context it can be used. For example. what does it mean - 'despite the adverb yesterday, we feel that the event is within a present time period'.

Comment: Those examples seem disparate to me. i.a  "He has got up at five o'clock." can imply an adverb that is not there: **recently or lately**.  And note:  got up here is BrE present perfect. ii.a is one of those "you can say what you like" but I would not hire that person as a speech coach. The others are what is usually said with a simple past tense.

Comment: ia and iia are fine for the reasons given by the authors -- note, though, the 'restrictive conditions' caveat. I think the authors would say that the example at the bottom of the screenshot is ungrammatical. In non-restrictive conditions, past adjuncts like "yesterday" and "last week" would normally be excluded since they divorce the situation from present time.

Comment: @BillJ What can be considered as a restricive condition?

Comment: You gave the 'restrictive conditions' that the authors referred to in your question.

Comment: This looks like a case of what [Jim McCawley called the "Hot News" sense](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299) of the English Perfect construction.